# Angular 2 hide textarea which the user unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, angular, checkbox

How can I hide a `textarea` when I unchecked a `checkbox` when the `textarea` is being rendered in `*ngFor`? So the checkbox should be bind with the textarea, right? It should only hide the `textarea` which the user unchecked and the others should stay visible.

I've been trying to figure out the easiest way of doing it though in my actual code its returning me `true` if the boxed is ticked and `false` if it's not, however it not hiding the `textarea` at all. The default value is true so it shows all the textarea as default.

For some reason this plnkr doesn't allow me use `[(ngMode)]` I think its a different RC of angular, but the example below is basically the problem I have when you uncheck the box it doesn't hide the textarea.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tOdtcmWxFB6vGuLyCqZS?p=preview

My original code:

```
<label for="inputSearch.name" style="float: left;">
    <input  type="checkbox" id="{{inputSearch.name}}" [checked]="chkProp" (click)="chkboxCookie()" [(ngModel)]="inputSearch.value"> {{inputSearch.name}}
 </label>

<div class="" *ngFor="let inputSearch of searchBoxCount" class="col-sm-12">
    <textarea name="{{inputSearch.name}}" id="{{inputSearch.name}}" rows="3" class="search-area-txt" attr.placeholder="Search {{inputSearch.name}}"  [(ngModel)]="inputSearch.value" *ngIf="chkProp || chkProp==true || inputSearch.name"></textarea>
    <p> {{inputSearch.name}} - {{inputSearch.value}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of `checkedUsers`, and set the checkbox to checked if the user **ISN'T** found in the array. Then, hide the `textarea` if the `user` **IS** found in the array.

THEN, on the checkboxes `change` pass the `user` to the change and add the user if they aren't in the array of `checkedUsers` and if they already are in it then remove them.

### [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/CpoA7s4ymM3TqATiqwIt?p=preview)

Here is what your component should look like. There are some **warnings** though, `name` on each user has to be unique or else add some sort of `id` property to them. Also, I am using `JSON.stringify` on the `checkedUsers` array and putting that in the `localStorage` so if that gets huge it will impact performance, but then you should be using a db anyways.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [`
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    `],
  template: `<p *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }} - {{ user.age }} </p>

   <div *ngFor="let user of users">
      <textarea name="{{user.name}}" id="{{ user.name }}" [class.hidden]="checkedUsers.indexOf(user) >= 0"></textarea>
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ user.name }}" [checked]="checkedUsers.indexOf(user) < 0" (click)="change(user)"/>
      <p>{{user.name}}</p>
   </div>

  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  public users: string;
  public checkedUsers = [];

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users = [{name: 'User1', age: '21'}, {name:'User2', age:'31'}];
    this.checkedUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("checkedUsers"));

    if(this.checkedUsers === null) {
      this.checkedUsers = [];
    } else {
      for(var i = 0; i < this.checkedUsers.length; i++) {
        var currCheckedUser = this.checkedUsers[i];
        for(var x = 0 ; x < this.users.length ; x++) {
          var currUser = this.users[x];
          if(currCheckedUser.name === currUser.name) {
            this.checkedUsers.splice(i, 1);
            this.checkedUsers.push(currUser);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  change(user): void {
    var indexOfItem = this.checkedUsers.indexOf(user);
    if(indexOfItem >= 0) {
      this.checkedUsers.splice(indexOfItem, 1);
    } else {
      this.checkedUsers.push(user);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("checkedUsers",  JSON.stringify(this.checkedUsers));
  }

}
```

Comment: Yeah kinda, but this does the opposite. Say the textareas are default to `true` so everything is visible, then if I unchecked `User1` that should hide but `User2` should stay visible, if both are unchecked then both should be hidden or visible if both are checked.

Comment: @nCore Ok, check the edits to the post and the updated plunker. I use an array of checked `users`, and if they check the box I push the `user` into the array and then on the `textarea` it is `hidden` if the `user` is found in the array

Comment: Yes, that's the one! thank you. I'd buy you a beer if you're near! .

Comment: haha Thanks for the offer, but the vote up and accepted answer do just fine! I glad to help out!

Comment: Actually just a quick question which is related to this one as well, will the check array work as well if I save the user[Array] in localStorage or Session? But ofc instead of saving `0, -1` it saves the `user.name` instead.

Comment: hmmm I believe so, if you `this.users = localStorage.getItem('<insert key here>');` inside the constructor, you should be just fine

Comment: `But ofc instead of saving 0, -1 it saves the user.name instead.` --what do you mean?

Comment: actually `0,-1` is wrong, what I meant is I want to save the `textarea` that are visible then remove them from the storage when user unchecked a `textarea` basically to save the setting, atm if you uncheck `User1` then refresh the page it returns back to default `true`.

Comment: do the users have a unique property like `id` or something, or is it just `name` and `age`?

Comment: Yeah just name and age but I want to just save the name as its value pair.

Comment: Going on the assumption that `name` is unique since there is no other unique identifier. I have updated the **PLUNKER** and the **post** to use localStorage to save. Sorry it took so long, it was a bit more complex

Comment: Oh I was along those lines of code earlier after asking about it, and yeah I agree that it will affect the performance once the array gets big. Its more of proof of concept. What would be the issue if there's no unique identifier on them? as the objs I'm trying to save is a sub-obj which only contains some items like (names, path, or say age) and name could have a value pair `name: 'id'` which might be the same on the other objs in the JSON response.

Comment: Thats great! It would just remove all the objs with the same 'name'. So if you had two objs with the same name they would both be hidden when you click one of them. In the `ngOnInit()` function this line would have to be changed `if(currCheckedUser.name === currUser.name) {` so that it compares the unique identifier. Or if you add a `break` in that `if()` then it remove the first instance of the object from the `checkedUsers` array

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="{{ user.name }}" [checked]="chkState" (change)="chkState = !chkState" />
```

However, you're going to run into a problem where it will hide all of your textareas. You need to use something unique to preserve their individual states.

Comment: the idea is only hide the textarea you've unchecked, I think that's why I'm trying to use `user.name` as `ngModel` because each user has unique name, however the plnkr wasn't allowing me use `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: can you give an example how else I can achieve it? so it'll only hide the textarea the user unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will work for you.

check and uncheck the check boxes.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [`
    .hidden {
      display: none;
    }
    `],
  template: `<p *ngFor="let user of users">{{ user.name }} - {{ user.age }} </p>

   <div *ngFor="let user of users">
      <textarea name="{{user.name}}" id="{{ user.name }}" [class.hidden]="chkState"> </textarea>
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ user.name }}" [checked]="chkState" (click)="change()"/>
      <p>{{user.name}}</p>
   </div>

  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  public users: string;
  public chkState = true;
  change(): void {
    this.chkState = !this.chkState;
  }
  constructor() {
    this.users = [{name: 'User1', age: '21'}, {name:'User2', age:'31'}];

  }
}
```

[Here is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/15nCI9nJPS85onEJ6ebi?p=preview)

Comment: that's hiding and show all the textarea, would only want to hide the textarea which I unchecked.

Comment: so if I unchecked `User1` it should hide that textarea relative to `User1`.